# Assign Wordpress Short code to PHP Variable?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to compare a email address held in a PHP variable with a email address held in a short code in Wordpress, this is what I've tried so far:

```
$email = 'someone@something.com';
$user_email = do_shortcode('[userinfo field="user_email"]');
echo var_dump(strcmp($user_email, $email) === 0);
```

But the `var_dump` always returns `false`, I'm positive they are the exact same string!

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump(strcmp($var, $var2));`  ? Also Check individual string using var_dump.

Comment: @Rikesh When I dump the vars one says string(48) and the other one says string(18), what does that mean?

Comment: Seems that your `do_shortcode` is not working as expected.

Comment: @WilliamL.: The shortcode returns something like that: `<span class="userinfo">test@example.com</span>` (with `var_dump` you would have seen that).

Comment: @vstm Your right, it does show that! Is there a way to just get the email address?

Comment: sidenote: You do not need to cast to string because `strcmp` expects string parameters to PHP will automatically do that (I removed that from your question as it's not necessary to illustrate your issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the `userinfo` shortcode returns the data wrapped in a `<span>` tag. To suppress the span tag you can use the `nospan`-attribute.

The [description of the plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-meta-shortcodes/) says the following:

> [userinfo nospan="true"] should eliminate the surrounding span tag so the output can be used inside URLs or similar applications

So your code should look like that:

```
$email = 'someone@something.com';
$user_email = do_shortcode('[userinfo field="user_email" nospan="true"]');
$var = (string) $user_email; // Casts to string
$var2 = (string) $email; // Casts to string
echo var_dump(strcmp($var, $var2) === 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the shortcode for that but just the Wordpress API function to obtain the current users email address:

```
$email = 'someone@something.com';

global $user_email;
get_currentuserinfo();

echo var_dump(strcmp($user_email, $email) === 0);
```

The Worpdress API function `get_currentuserinfo()` sets the global variable `$user_email` to the email address of the current user as a string.

Answer (score 0):

See if there are any spaces and if any of the string needs to be trimmed, because if both the strings are same then your code seems to work already.

```
$email = 'someone@something.com';
$user_email = 'someone@something.com';
$var = (string) $user_email; // Casts to string
$var2 = (string) $email; // Casts to string
echo var_dump(strcmp($var, $var2) === 0);
```

Returns `bool(true)`

Probably `do_shortcode('[userinfo field="user_email"]');` needs to be trimmed. Also you can simply echo `$user_email` before comparison to see if there is any unexpected value there.

Comment: When I dump the vars one says string(48) and the other one says string(18), does this mean I need to trim the strings?

Comment: yes this means strings are not equal, what does a simple echo suggest? do they look equal? are there any unexpected characters?

Comment: The echo just shows string(48) followed by the email address and string(18) followed by the same email address, its exactly the same.

Comment: also view source not view in browser. there can be HTML tags that get hidden.