# Serve random arrays in do_shortcode()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Based on a code found here: [Assign Wordpress Short code to PHP Variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287361/assign-wordpress-short-code-to-php-variable)

I've created this code to serve list of 5 categories:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'inject_shortcode', 5 );

function inject_shortcode() {
  if( is_shop() ) {
    $my_header = '<br><h2 class="head" align="center">TOP BRANDS WE STOCK</h2>';
    $my_shortcode_string = do_shortcode('[ux_product_categories style="normal" col_spacing="xsmall" columns="5" columns__sm="3" columns__md="5" animate="bounceInUp" ids="33,20,53,55,59,56,58,57,54" text_size="small" text_padding="0px 0px 0px 0px"]');

    echo $my_header;
    echo $my_shortcode_string;
  }
}
```

But this only serves with the first 5 categories on the list.

Now..
I want to take it a step forward and randomize the list of categories,
So each page refresh, it'll select 5 different categories.

I came up with the following code:
But it's not working,
What do I misses here?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'inject_shortcode', 5 );

function inject_shortcode() {
  if( is_shop() ) {
    $random_categories = array(33,20,53,55,59,56,58,57,54);
    $random_keys = array_rand($random_categories,5);

    $my_header = '<br><h2 class="head" align="center">TOP BRANDS WE STOCK</h2>';
    $my_shortcode_string = do_shortcode('[ux_product_categories style="normal" col_spacing="xsmall" columns="5" columns__sm="3" columns__md="5" animate="bounceInUp"' && 'ids=' && $random_categories[$random_keys[0]] && 'text_size="small" text_padding="0px 0px 0px 0px"]');

    echo $my_header;
    echo $my_shortcode_string;
  }
}
```

Thank you,
Amit.

Answer (score 0):

`&&` is the logical and. You need to use `.` for string concatenation:

```
$my_shortcode_string = do_shortcode('[ux_product_categories style="normal" col_spacing="xsmall" columns="5" columns__sm="3" columns__md="5" animate="bounceInUp" ids="' . $random_categories[$random_keys[0]] . '"text_size="small" text_padding="0px 0px 0px 0px"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$random_categories[$random_keys[0]]` will only ever return the first element from `$random_keys`. You will need to build your string of IDs before you echo it to your shortcode.

eg,

```
foreach( $random_keys as $random_key ) {
    $output_ids[] = $random_categories[$random_key];
}
```

and then `implode()` the array into a string for your output:

`$my_shortcode_string = do_shortcode('[ux_product_categories style="normal" col_spacing="xsmall" columns="5" columns__sm="3" columns__md="5" animate="bounceInUp" ids="' . implode(',', $output_ids) . '"text_size="small" text_padding="0px 0px 0px 0px"]');`

*(I'm assuming that your shortcode requires the IDs as a comma-separated list, if not change the `','` part of `implode(',', $output_ids)` to whatever it requires as a separator.)*

Comment: Guys
This is great.
Thank you so much.
Amit.